# Mesclar Querys de Métodos diferentes em um unico JSON

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando, criar um select onde me retorna dados em json e depois criei um método que seria uma "function de banco" que é outro select trazendo um resultado, como faria pra justar tudo isso e trazer um json só?

```
    class ConsolidatedOrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    json_date = []

    dt_inicio = fc_inicio(931101)

    json_date = Order.left_outer_joins(:load, :user, :pallet_kind, :order_priority, step: [:status, :role])
                     .select('orders.*','loads.*', 'statuses.name as Status', 'pallet_kinds.name as Tipo_de_Pallet', 'order_priorities.name as Prioridade')
                     .where('orders.step' => 500)
                     .as_json

    render json: json_date
  end

  def fc_inicio(order_id, status_id = 3, role_id = 1)
    OrderHistory.joins(:step)
                .select('order_histories.start')
                .where('steps.role_id' => role_id, 'steps.status_id' => status_id, 'order_histories.order_id' => order_id)
                .where.not(end: nil)
                .limit(1)
                .to_json
  end
```

Comment: Mano, usa o método merge() conforme: https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge
Se os dois métodos retornam um json,no final de um dos métodos basta colocar .merge(nome-do-outro-metodo). Lembrando que se nos dois métodos tiver chaves de nomes iguais, ele irá substituir o antigo pelo novo que esta sendo mergeado.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_unido = fc_inicio.merge(json_date)
```

Só tome cuidado pois chaves repetidas podem ser sobrescritas